# Dependency issues while installing gcc 7.3 from Jonathon F's PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc

I'm trying to install the latest gcc-7 package from [Jonathon F's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3). Looks like finally now there is a successful build for amd64 as of 2018-02-23.

I met with the following dependency issues when running `sudo apt-get install gcc-7`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gcc-7 : Depends: cpp-7 (= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04 is to be installed
         Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04 is to be installed
         Depends: binutils (>= 2.28) but 2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Previously, I did install `gcc-7` from Ubuntu's ppa but that was for `7.2`. I have removed that package.

Running Synaptic, here's a list of suspicious packages:

[image: upgradeable packages in Synaptic]

Any suggestions on how I can resolve these dependency issues and install gcc 7.3?

Comment: With all respect to JonathonF why you ask here? And of course you can remove PPA with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: my understanding is that Ubuntu ppa only has gcc 7.2. JonathanF's gcc 7.3 is the only way to go? Thanks for the link, let me check it out. I thought someone might have had the same specific issue with regards to this package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that gcc-7 (7.3) is broken in [Jonathon F's GCC 7.3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3). I can't install GCC 7.3 on clean Xenial system (without any other PPA):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-7 : Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is to be installed
         Depends: binutils (>= 2.28) but 2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.6 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ grep -r ppa /etc/apt/sources.list*
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-gcc-7_3-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-gcc-7_3-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.3/ubuntu xenial main
```

So you should purge this PPA and use gcc 7.2 from [“PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads (restricted)” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=xenial):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then [contact Jonathon F](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+contactuser) and inform him about the problem.

**Update.** But I found [other PPA `ppa:jonathonf/gcc` from Jonathon F](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc?field.series_filter=xenial). I can install gcc 7.3 from it.

```
#sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test # remove starting # if PPA added before
#sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3 # remove starting # if PPA added before
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:jonathonf/gcc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 # will install 7.3.0-5ubuntu1~16.04.york0
```

and even `gcc-8` (version *8-20180218-1ubuntu1~16.04.york0*).

Comment: Oh, you mean the gcc-7 (7.3) from Jonathan F is actually broken even though the build status shows success?

Comment: I'm referring to the status shown here: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3/+build/14387533

Comment: It does not install on my clean Xenial system. It may be successfully built, but does not install (see above).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. At least I know it's not just me....

Comment: See update above. We can install gcc 7.3 and even 8 from other PPA (`ppa:jonathonf/gcc`). Great work, @JonathonF !

Comment: @Ryan please remove your comment from here and open new question with your personal experience and complete details.

Comment: can i install gcc-6 on xenial using this same method for gcc-7

Comment: @user123 You have to check this by yourself, many things may change after 2 years.

Comment: ya i checked, its not working

Comment: `cpp-7 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-23ubuntu2~16.04.york0) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~16.04 is to be installed`

Comment: Thanks for comments, but 16.04 is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the ppa from jonathonf using command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3
```

a message is displayed in logs

> This is built against, and requires, ppa:jonathonf/gcc
>    More info: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3

Adding the ppa resolves the dependency issue

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7
```

The dependeency issues was

> he following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    gcc-7 : Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 7.3.0-23ubuntu2~16.04.york0) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 is to be installed
>            Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-23ubuntu2~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.